# Trigger Performance Degredation (To use or not to use)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've created this trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `increment_daily_called_count` BEFORE UPDATE ON `list` 
FOR EACH ROW begin
  if (NEW.called_count != OLD.called_count) then
    set NEW.daily_called_count = OLD.daily_called_count(NEW.called_count-OLD.called_count);
    set NEW.modify_date = OLD.modify_date;    
  end if;
end
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The database table this runs on is accessed and used by 100's of different scripts in the larger system and the reason for the trigger is so I don't have to hunt down every little place in these scripts where the called_count might get updated...

My concern is that, because this particular table gets modified constantly (I'm talking dozens of times per second), is this going to put undue strain on the database? Am I better off in the long run hunting down all the called_count update queries in the myriad scripts and adding daily_called_count = daily_called_count+1?

Some specifics I'd like to know the answer to here:

- Does use of this trigger essentially make this 3 separate update queries where it was once a single query, or is MySQL smart enough to bundle these queries?
- Is there a performance argument for hunting down and modifying the originating queries over using the trigger?
- Could this trigger cause any unforeseen weirdness that I'm not anticipating?

Answer (score 5):

Two disclaimers:

1. I have not worked with MySQL in a very long time, and never used triggers with it.  I can only speak from *general* experience with RDBMS's.
2. The only way to really know anything for sure is to run a performance test.

That said, my attempts to answer with semi-educated guesses (from experience):

> > Does use of this trigger essentially make this 3 separate update queries where it was once a single query, or is mysql smart enough to bundle these queries?

I don't think it's a separate update in the sense of statement execution.    But you are adding a computation overhead cost to each row.

However, what I am more worried about is the row-by-row nature of this trigger.  It literally says `FOR EACH ROW`.  Generally speaking, row-by-row operations scale poorly in a RDBMS compared to SET-based operations.  MS SQL Server runs statement-level triggers where the entire set of affected rows is passed in, so a row-by-row operation is not necessary.  This may not be an option in MySQL triggers - I really don't know.

> > Is there a performance argument for hunting down and modifying the originating queries over using the trigger?

It would certainly make the system do less work.  How much the performance impact is, numerically, I can't say.  You'd have to test.  If it's only a 1% difference, the trigger is probably fine.  If it's 50%, well, it'd be worth hunting down all the code.  Since hunting down the code is a burden, I suspect it's either embedded in an application or comes dynamically from an ORM.  If that is the case, as long as the performance cost of the trigger is acceptable, I'd rather stick to the trigger as it keeps a DB-specific detail in the DB.

Measure, measure, measure.

> > Could this trigger cause any unforeseen weirdness that I'm not anticipating?

Caching comes to mind.  If these columns are part of something an application reads and caches, its cache invalidation is probably tied to when it thinks it changed the data.  If the database changes data underneath it, like with a trigger, caching may result in stale data being processed.

Answer (score 4):

First, thanks to @Brandon for his response. I built my own script and test database to benchmark and solve my question... While I don't have a good answer to points 1 and 3, I do have an answer on the performance question...

To note I am using 10.0.24-MariaDB on our development server which didn't have anything else running on it at the time.

Here are my results...

Updating 100000 rows:

```
TRIGGER QUERY TIME: 6.85960197 SECONDS
STANDARD QUERY TIME: 5.90444183 SECONDS
```

Updating 200000 rows:

```
TRIGGER QUERY TIME: 13.19935203 SECONDS
STANDARD QUERY TIME: 11.88235188 SECONDS
```

You folks can decide for yourselves which way to go.

Comment: Are you aware that what you measured is basically I/O capacity of your hard drive? These numbers are meaningless unless someone has the exact same HDD subsystem as you do. Triggers add overhead, as every kind of extra work. If you want performance, do the least possible amount of work using the fastest hardware (yes, I know it's obvious). Also, if you wrap this in a transaction block, then you'll be able to utilize your drive's bandwith and save I/O, which lets you increase the performance. On the other hand, If I were you, I'd use event scheduler and run a procedure periodically to clean up.

Comment: The numbers aren't meaningless, while yes someone else with a different system will get different results, for a fairly standard MariaDB server the numbers indicate a slight increase in transaction speed for the non-trigger method, just because you don't find this information useful doesn't mean someone else won't.