# MySQL | Automatically count related tables as a counter (one to many)

Tags: mysql, count, sql-update

### Problem

Is there a way to automatically count related tables (one to Many), where the count will automatically increment / decrement depending if we add or remove a related item.

So, I could obviously just do a COUNT, but for perfomance reason it is expensive millions of records and are queries many many times.
As I solution, rather then count every time, I would actually create a *counter* where **add 1 when adding a new related item or remove 1 when deleting or de-ferencing another item**

In order to do that, I may just create another table that serves as a counter, and query that table without counting.

#### Is there a better way, preferably, that is automatic?

### Example

**schema**

```sql
create table object
(
    object_id       int auto_increment   primary key,
    name            varchar(120)         not null
);


create table item
(
    item_id       varchar(63)         not null,
    object_id int                     not null,
    primary key (object_id, item_id)
);
insert into object (name) VALUES ("hello");
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES
      ("item1", 1),
      ("item2", 1),
      ("item3", 1),
      ("item4", 1);
```

Object "hello" has 4 items:

```sql
select count(*) from item where object_id = 1;
-- ouput: 4
```

However, I found that as a work around, I can create a counter (**that is using back-end Python**) that each time you do a *CRUD* operation, the counter is updated. For example:

**Counter schema**

```sql
create table item_counter
(
    counter bigint                  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    object_id int                   NOT NULL  primary key
)
```

So now the **ORM** in the could we would do something like this (again, it will be handle in Python, but it doesn't matter is just as example:

```sql
-- create object AND item_counter
insert into object (name) VALUES ("hello");
-- create in the same time a counter 
insert into item_counter (object_id) VALUES ((SELECT object_id FROM object where name = "hello"));
-- create items
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item1", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item2", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item3", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
insert into item (item_id, object_id) VALUES  ("item4", 2);
update item_counter set counter = counter + 1 where object_id = 2;
-- select the counter instead
select counter from item_counter where object_id = 2;
```

That if it was in python it would look like

```py
# pseudo ORM code 
class ItemORM:

    def save(self, item_id, object_id):
        self.orm.save(item_id, object_id)
        counter = self.orm.get_counter(object_id)
        counter.add()
```

So, is there a better way, especially, something that MySQL may do automatically?

#### More Context

In case you want to know why, let's say that I am working in a large code base, which lots of legacy code **and API dependecies used by external clients** and currently there isn't a **counter implementation** but is merely my idea to overcome it. So, changing large part of the code is very risky, instead, tweak come MYSQL tables may be a better solution.

Comment: Answered at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/321477/150107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL alone doesn't have any automatic way of doing what you describe. It's up to you to implement a solution, or use an additional technology with MySQL.

I can think of at least the following solutions:

- Use triggers to maintain your counter. Increment on INSERT, decrement on DELETE. You might run into throughput problems if your rate of concurrent inserts and delete is very high.

  ```
  create trigger ti after insert on item
  for each row 
    update item_counter 
    set counter = counter + 1
    where object_id = NEW.object_id;

  create trigger td after delete on item
  for each row
    update item_counter 
    set counter = counter - 1
    where object_id = OLD.object_id;
  ```

  Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/tgJM0I4m
- Use a materialized view. PlanetScale recently offered a product (in beta as of November 2022) that does something like a materialized view, but it's more complex than that. Read their description: https://planetscale.com/blog/how-planetscale-boost-serves-your-sql-queries-instantly
- Use a data warehouse. An OLTP database like MySQL typically stores tables as rows, so it's optimized for CRUD type queries. A data warehouse or OLAP database stores tables as columns, so aggregate queries like the one you describe are its strength. But this means setting up a separate database technology, and syncing your MySQL data to the data warehouse continually.
- WARP is a MySQL 8.0 storage engine that seems to combine both a column-store and materialized views. See https://www.leapdb.com/ I worked with the developer who created WARP, he's brilliant.

Comment: "run into throughput problems" Let's say that we are creating, updating, deleting milions of times a day the item record. So having a trigger or not having would it make a big difference you think? Using this implementation (done by @Akina in a different anser) https://dbfiddle.uk/w0G1DO4Z  you say that would impact performance so much?

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797444/trigger-performance-degredation-to-use-or-not-to-use

Comment: @FedericoBaù, I added an example of how I would write it, differently from Akina's answer.

Comment: Regarding performance, you will have to test that. It might be adequate performance for your needs. I can't predict because I don't know the power of your server, and I don't know the rate of inserts in your application. You will have to test it.

Comment: yes it always needs a test. But I was asking if overall, by knowledge you would consider it a good solution prior to test. That is, if you know that is going to be a very very very busy db where the `item` is going to have many many CRUD operation, would you consider it a good *possible* solution?

Comment: For example, something that I could say on top of my head even before tests, (and most programming languages) is that a list (or array whatever is called in that language) that has many entry and we need to insert, remove , pop in random index in most cases is going to perform badly, so I would just go for a mapping instead (hasg table, key - value etc..) you know what I mean? So in this case, I would not even test the  array and I  would go straigh with a mapping and I could tell you "that won't work" bla bla.

Comment: Any of the solutions I listed can work. I did not list solutions that won't work. It's up to you to test which one is best for your environment.

Comment: Off corse they work :) i meant bit something else but nevermind your answer is good. I ll run tests yes;)